# Соединение данных по дате и ключевому полю в BigquerySql

Tags: sql, join, bigquery

Есть две таблицы: developer_rates и tracks. 
В первой хранятся треки разработчиков:
[image: Таблица с треками]

```
CREATE TABLE tracks 
(
  track_id INT PRIMARY, --ID трека
  date DATE NOT NULL, --Дата трека
  timefact DECIMAL, --Время по треку
  developer_id INT --ID разработчика
);
```

```
INSERT tracks 
  (track_id, date, timefact, developer_id)
VALUES 
(0,'2021-12-15', 8, 0),
(1,'2021-12-30', 2, 0),
(2,'2021-12-05', 4, 1),
(3,'2021-12-11', 2.2, 2),
(4,'2021-12-12', 6, 1)
```

Во второй - данные о том, какая ставка и когда была установлена разработчику:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE developer_rates
(
  developer_rate_id INT PRIMARY, --ID записи о ставке
  developer_id INT NOT NULL, --ID разработчика
  rate DECIMAL, --Размер ставки
  starteddate DATE --Дата, с которой действует ставка
);
```

```
INSERT INTO developer_rates 
  (developer_rate_id, developer_id, rate,starteddate)
VALUES
  (0, 1, 300, '2021-12-01'),
  (1, 0, 200, '2021-12-09'),
  (2, 2, 400, '2021-12-10'),
  (3, 1, 400, '2021-12-11'),
  (4, 0, 250, '2021-12-18')
```

Мне нужно свести эти данные воедино, чтобы для каждой даты трека (поле date) разработчику (по полю developer_id) выставлялась его ставка на текущую дату.

На данный момент, я делаю это так:

```
WITH salarys AS (
  SELECT
    developer_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(starteddate, rate)) AS str
  FROM developer_rates
  GROUP BY developer_id
)
SELECT
  t.track_id,
  t.date
  t.timefact,
  (SELECT IFNULL(rate, 0)
    FROM UNNEST(salarys.str) 
    WHERE starteddate <= date 
    ORDER BY starteddate DESC 
    LIMIT 1) AS devRate
FROM tracks AS t
LEFT JOIN salarys
  ON t.developer_id = salarys.developer_id
```

И получаю данные:

```
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| track_id |    date    | timefact | devRate |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+
|    0     | 2021-12-15 |     8    |   200   |
|    1     | 2021-12-30 |     2    |   250   |
|    2     | 2021-12-05 |     4    |   300   |
|    3     | 2021-12-11 |    2.2   |   200   |
|    4     | 2021-12-12 |     6    |   400   |
+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Но использование множественных операций сортировки - плохая практика для Google BigQuery, а массивы и структуры - не поддерживаются DataStudio. Да и в целом операция получилась ресурсоёмкой.

Есть ли возможность соединить эти данные, не используя создание массива структур и сортировки? (В приоритете - избавиться от сортировки).

З.Ы.: Нэйминг переменных и таблиц видоизменён в сторону упрощения, просьба не сильно кидать тапки.

Comment: Дайте - структуры в виде CREATE TABLE скриптов, пример данных в виде INSERT INTO скриптов (не более десятка записей), требуемый для таких данных результат, форматированной таблицей, с подробными пояснениями.

Comment: Добавил, нужно что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще один вариант, используя аггрегацию вместо аналитической функции:

```
SELECT
  t.track_id,
  t.date,
  t.timefact,
  ARRAY_AGG(r.rate ORDER BY r.starteddate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS rate
FROM tracks AS t
LEFT JOIN developer_rates r
  ON t.developer_id = r.developer_id
  AND t.date >= r.starteddate
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Технически здесь нет сортировки, только выбор максимального значения (ARRAY_AGG + LIMIT 1) и хеширование (GROUP BY). Производительность думаю примерно такая же как у решения Akina. Теоретически масштабируемость лучше, но на практике врядли будет заметна разница.

Comment: К сожалению, именно что технически - сортировка здесь есть (по крайней мере, так это воспринимает BigQUery.

Comment: Какую сортировку вы имеете в виду? Тут ORDER BY LIMIT 1 - это не сортировка, это выбор одного элемента - в памяти будет храниться только один элемент на группу, и стоимость линейная.

Comment: Протестирую - отпишусь по результатам. Пока могу сказать только то, что предложенный Akina вариант оказался очень ресурсоёмким (х2 от моего).

Comment: С точки зрения BigQuery ваш вариант оказался эффективнее по занимаемому времени слотов, но (возможно, из-за нюансов конкретно моего скрипта) - менее эффективен по объёму используемых данных.
В целом, задачу выполняет, т.к. оптимизация времени слота для меня важнее.

Answer (score 1):

Если не считать непонятно откуда взявшегося `devRate=200` для `track_id=3`, то

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       tr.track_id, 
       tr.date,
       tr.timefact, 
       FIRST_VALUE(dr.rate) OVER (PARTITION BY tr.track_id 
                                  ORDER BY dr.starteddate DESC) devRate
FROM tracks tr
JOIN developer_rates dr ON tr.developer_id = dr.developer_id
                       AND tr.date >= dr.starteddate
```

Comment: Через оконную функцию это интересный путь избавиться от массива, но сортировка остаётся. В любом случае, спасибо за вариант избавления хотя бы от него.

Comment: @Antidjagger Избавиться от сортировки вообще можно только за счёт итеративного фуллскана таблицы - и далеко не факт, что bigquery это вообще умеет. Причём и это возможно лишь при условии, что дефолтный порядок отдачи записей таблицы соответствует требуемой сортировке (может быть правдой в случае, когда кластерный индекс соответствует такой сортировке).

Comment: Можете посоветовать, что можно почитать на эту тему?
Просто, всё, что мне приходит в голову - это промежуточная таблица результатов, в которой будет соотношение каждого дня года с каждой записью о ставке, но тогда задержка от момента обновления данных до момента их актуализации в итоговом запросе становится огромной.

Comment: @Antidjagger Пожалуйста, определите точно, о какой теме речь.

Comment: Я, в силу не очень большого опыта не понял, что вы подразумеваете под "итеративным фуллсканом"

Comment: @Antidjagger Посмотрите, как эмулируют ROW_NUMBER() в MySQL пятой версии с использованием user-defined variables и правильно заданной сортировки. При этом все записи таблицы перебираются по одной в строго заданном порядке, и полученные при обработке предыдущей записи значения используются при обработке следующей. Аналогом может быть рекурсивный CTE, который на каждом очередном шаге выбирает строго одну запись.